# Replacing ' (APOSTROPHE) in a list of string

Tags: string, python-2.7, text, replace

I want to replace ' in a list of string using python. currently i am using a method for replacing characters as shown below,
**replace('+', ' ')** 
Apparently, i cannot use the same method to replace the Apostrophe.

Comment: Use double quote: `replace("'",, ' ') `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just escape it.

```
replace('\'', ' ')
```

Comment: @rando And before you ask another question. If you need to replace a stroke, you escape it with another one: `replace('\\', ' ')`